# How to install old version of composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to install old version of composer. My commands are:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'baf1608c33254d00611ac1705c1d9958c817a1a33bce370c0595974b342601bd80b92a3f46067da89e3b06bff421f182') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php --version=1.4.1
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

But it didn't install composer. I check with the command `composer -v` but unfortunately it didn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: If you want to install a specific version & not able to install it in that case you can install a lower version & and then can update it by 

composer self-update 1.4.1    with specific version

Answer (score 83, accepted):

These commands will install composer binary in `composer.phar` file in current working directory. You may try to verify this by running `php composer.phar -v` command. `composer` command will most like point to some global installation in your system - you need to move new binary to correct place, so it could be recognized as global command ([see docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally)):

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

---

If you have already Composer installed, you should able to use [`self-update`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#self-update-selfupdate-) command to downgrade to any version:

```
composer self-update 1.4.1
```

or

```
sudo -H composer self-update 1.4.1
```

Comment: I install the latest version of composer then change to the version 1.4.1 with the command composer self-update 1.4.1  and it worked thank you

Comment: I've got problem with compose 2.0 when my project was running successfully at version 1.8.0. Use "composer self-update [version]" solves the problem. Really a paint like unexpected errors happen from no-where.

Comment: This is definitely the way it seems to change composer version. Although I have installed version 1 with the folowing: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --version=1.10.16`

Comment: composer self-update 1.4.1 this will break the composer and it starts throwing error [ErrorException]                                     
  Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Comment: `1.4.1` is pretty old, it probably won't work on latest PHP. If you just want to go back to 1.x line, use `composer self-update --1` (or `composer self-update 1.10.17` if your composer does not support `--1` flag).

Comment: composer self-update --rollback to roll back to original version.

Answer (score 35):

If you came here searching for downgrading from composer 2.0 to 1.0

`composer self-update --1`

Comment: I think `sudo` is not necessary in most cases, as it changes the owner of .composer to root user.

Comment: It gave me permission denied.

Comment: @Jovylle Use `sudo` in start

Answer (score 28):

Curl can be used to download a specific version:

```
curl -O "https://getcomposer.org/download/1.10.17/composer.phar"
chmod a+x composer.phar
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have installed composer v2, and want to install composer v1 in addition you can do:

```
wget https://getcomposer.org/composer-1.phar
chmod a+x composer-1.phar
sudo mv composer-1.phar /usr/local/bin/composer1
```

And use `composer1` on old projects:

```
cd <OLD-PROJECT>
composer1 install
```

Comment: This works for me, as quite often I need to do some work on older projects. You just gotta avoid installing packages globally.