# Laravel PackageManifest.php: Undefined index: name

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just trying to deploy my application and I just ran composer update on my server and I got the following error:

In PackageManifest.php line 122:
Undefined index: name

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I had a same issue, but on my local env (docker). I fixed it by using composer update outside docker container, so basically using php and composer installed on my Mac. If you use docker you can try to do the same thing, maybe not the best way how to fix it but it works. :)

Comment: I tried so many answers below but only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177995/laravel-packagemanifest-php-undefined-index-name#comment118778877_65651152 worked for me.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

As a temporary fix, try this, it worked for me, in the following file:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php
```

Find line 116 and comment it:

```
$packages = json_decode($this->files->get($path), true);
```

Add these lines after the line you just commented:

```
$installed = json_decode($this->files->get($path), true);
$packages = $installed['packages'] ?? $installed;
```

The whole block might look like this (with added comments)

```
    if ($this->files->exists($path = $this->vendorPath.'/composer/installed.json')) {
        // packages is all the files from the path
        // $packages = json_decode($this->files->get($path), true);

        // get all the files from the path
        $installed = json_decode($this->files->get($path), true);

        // if installed contains packages key, use it, otherwise use the whole thing
        $packages = $installed['packages'] ?? $installed;
    }
```

Comment: The problem here is I just don't want to change the core files.

Comment: This is not a great solution. You should not edit vendor files like that. What if somebody else install your dependencies from your composer.lock.json?

Comment: For a temporary fix it works like a charm.

Comment: Running composer update now makes that change to PackageManifest.php without any need for manual editing.

Comment: Never make a change in core files in vendor directory

Comment: Line number 116

Comment: As @svetipetar mentioned running composer update will make the changes to the same file, no need to manually editing and updating

Comment: Best Solution. I will suggest If anyone can't to composer install . He can try with this `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` first then follow this Answer steps. Great Thank you

Comment: This is not a solution. You must not touch to core files. This is only composer version problem. Laravel 5.6 needs composer 1.1. If you're trying to use composer 2.1 then causes this problem. Downgrading composer to 1.1 then everything is fine.

Comment: This solution works for me. First i changed the vendors file, then composer update and finally I put the vendor file whit the previous code again. For me was ok

Comment: Even in 2023 this works.

Comment: A life savor!!!

Answer (score 216):

I had the same problem, I just execute the command:

```
composer update
```

this will updated the composer.lock file.
After that worked like a charm.

Comment: I don't know why people accept downgrading composer or changing the source files of Laravel as a solution, while this is the right way to fix it.

Comment: @shamaseen because you don't want to run "composer update" on a production environment.

Comment: This will update all your library files to their latest version constrained by composer.json. You may or may not want to do this. https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update-u

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works without editting any files!

Comment: This works, the situation is that all dependencies will be updated to the latest version and probably some scripts will break, so take that on consideration.

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 65):

I found [this issue on the composer GitHub repo](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9340) that helped a lot

I updated my Laravel framework from 5.8 to 5.8.38, following the table displayed in that issue and the error disappeared.

This [Laravel blog post](https://blog.laravel.com/upgrading-to-composer-v2) also helps

If you can't upgrade Laravel, you can just stay with Composer 1 by running

```sh
composer self-update --1
```

Comment: This reply works for me when upgrading Laravel 5.5 to 6.x

Comment: Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 2.0.13

Comment: works for me too

Comment: Thank you, your answer fixed the problem but didn't clearly explain why. The actual problem is that the laravel version we're running is not compatible with composer 2.x. Both downgrading composer to 1.x or upgrading to a compatible laravel fix the problem. https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9340#issuecomment-716210369

Answer (score 49):

I had the same problem.

In my case downgrading the composer version fixed the problem.

They updated Composer 4 times within 2 days - I think they had a problem with their newest updates.

In my case version 1.10.1 was the version to go with.

```
sudo composer self-update --1
```

I hope it'll work.

Comment: how you downgrade it?

Comment: This is only a correct temporary workaround if `composer update` doesn't fix it. Downgrading Composer is not a solution.

Comment: this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335911/how-to-install-old-version-of-composer @SL5net

Comment: I downgraded from 2.0.11 to 1.10.20 using `composer self-update 1.10.20`  and the error disappeared. But I cannot update to composer 2.x....

Comment: Instead of composer install, you can use composer update. It works for me

Comment: composer self-update --1 ... this command helped me

Comment: @AlexAngelico Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 2.0.13

Comment: @leuan Updating all of your packages isn't a solution either. `composer update` updates all of your dependencies. That may not be desired at the time of trying to get past this error.

Answer (score 47):

I recently switched **composer 2.0.8** and my Laravel version is **6.20.27**

To solve this issue:

### Step 1:

Delete `compose.lock` File

### Step 2:

Install dependencies.

```sh
composer install
```

Comment: This solved it for me too without need to downgrade composer. I think this should be the approved answer. Perhaps downgrading composer also solves it, but in my case and in my opinion it's less ideal to downgrade.

Comment: i think this is the same of not deleting the composer.lock file and just run composer update.

Comment: @kapitan It is not. `composer update` looks into composer.lock file and updates each dependencies to newer version, if newer version is available. But `composer install` with deleting `composer.lock` file doesn't care what has been previously installed, it installs everything as fresh of  `composer.json` file

Comment: @BedramTamang -I actually knew what's happening on both cases. I am actually talking about the version of the packages that will be installed at the end because both will install the newest package.

Comment: this one should be marked as correct answer.

Comment: Worked for me too; Laravel 5.8.28. After deleting the composer.lock, all packages were installed successfully. Then checked version, it had upgraded to 5.8.38

Comment: This issue appeared when I changed the folder name of the project. And this is the fix that worked for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 30):

I had a problem like this, and also tried `composer self-update --stable`, but there was no result. So, I found that this file belongs to the Laravel framework. So the following command resolved this issue:

**$ composer update laravel/framework**

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work for me. I still got the same error: `In PackageManifest.php line 122:                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                       
  Undefined index: name`

Comment: This worked for me and I prefer it over updating all the packages

Answer (score 20):

In my case downgrading the composer version fixed the problem.

```
sudo composer self-update --1
```

Answer (score 20):

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9340#issuecomment-716210369

As stated in here, your laravel version may conflict with composer 2

```
composer update laravel/framework
```

should fix your problem :D

Comment: Thank you!!! I must have updated to Composer 2 at some point but was still running Laravel 6.0 in this repo. I needed to do a LOT of manual upgrades to get this working. But what you pointed to was definitely my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the same issue. I Saw my Laravel framework version is `"laravel/framework": "6.0"`
So just put the cap before the version and it starts working fine.
`"laravel/framework": "^6.0"`

Comment: Looks like there may be a few different causes of this issue, each with different solutions, but this was what worked for me.
In context, upgrading from 5.8 where every .1 is a major version change, but on 6+ every .1 is a minor version.
So locking to "6.0" or "6.0.*" kept it on "6.0.4" and avoided the rest of the version updates (currently "6.20.16")
This bug existed on "6.0.4" but was fixed after.

Comment: I also faced the same issue but couldn't fix it by applying almost all solutions listed here. However, this solution triggered something in me and I checked my framework version once again and found that it was entered wrongly(I was testing something on the previous day). I put the right framework number and the issues got disappeared instantly. Thank You!

Comment: This was the solution to migrating from Laravel 5.8 to 6.0. Thanks, you saved me some time.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to solve this issue is

delete **composer.lock** file from your project.

Run `composer install`

Comment: Thanks, its works for me!

Comment: Warning: this will update all packages. If you want to avoid updating packages, go to `vendor/composer` and remove `installed.json`

Answer (score 8):

Running the following command worked for me. Maybe this will help someone needy.

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 8):

I removed my vendor folder and composer.lock and ran `composer install` again. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 6):

Some versions of composer give this error, the version 1.10.20 doesn't throw this error

```
composer self-update 1.10.20
composer install
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 5):

Running `composer update` worked for my project with Laravel 5.7

Comment: This may be the correct answer but another user has already posted something similar. When writing a new answer please try to include additional information or examples that the other answers don't have.

Answer (score 3):

For my `Laravel 5.7` project deleting `vendor` folder and `composer.lock` file fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution:

- Delete the `vendor` folder.
- run `composer install`

Don't use `--no-scripts`. This will cause a problem, and will not create the appropiate folders which the file `PackageManifest.php` and others need.

- run `composer update`

This is so you don't have problems with bugs in the file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it is worked for me, in the following file:

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php

Find this line and comment on it

```
$packages = json_decode($this->files->get($path), true);
```

Add two new lines after the above-commented line

```
$installed = json_decode($this->files->get($path), true);
$packages = $installed['packages'] ?? $installed;
```

Comment: never change the vendor source files. This changes will be overwritten on new update

Comment: still no side effect for me. @natghi

Comment: @AnujShrestha you are correct. still, I have not met that issue again when I updated

Comment: it is because the package manager has not updated that specific file, but if they change the file, then all the update you did in the vendor folder will be gone on the next composer update. And there are many proper answers for this issue already. Yours is just bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fix without making updates and composer updates

just go to vendor/composer and remove `installed.json`

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't  seem to fix the `undefined index: name` issue

Answer (score 2):

Running the following command fixed it for us

```
composer self-update --stable
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I got the message `You are already using composer version 2.0.4 (stable channel).`

Answer (score 2):

No need to force an upgrade on your packages (running `composer update` on production is not recommended anyway) or downgrade your Composer if it's on version 2.

If you have a website that requires Composer v1 for updates (because, for example, v2 causes errors) and you have version v2 installed globally, the quickest solution is:

## Step 1

Download the latest stable 1.x **composer.phar** from https://getcomposer.org/download/ (under Manual Download).

## Step 2

Place the downloaded **composer.phar** file in the root of your project (where the **composer.json** file resides).

## Step 3

Run your command using the **composer.phar** file. Example:

```
php composer.phar install
```

Answer (score 1):

To downgrade composer to an old version:

```
composer self-update <version>
```

Example:

```
composer self-update 1.10.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated to Composer `2.0.11` and I had the error. Downgraded to Composer `1.10.20`, it worked great, BUT IT'S VERY VERY SLOW.

So for those like me who don't want to change the vendor code, and still want Composer `2.0.x` know that it was a kind of bug in Laravel, and Laravel has fixed it in minor versions (or hotfixes). I was using Laravel `5.7.9` and my `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php ->build()` was like:

```
if ($this->files->exists($path = $this->vendorPath.'/composer/installed.json')) {
    $packages = json_decode($this->files->get($path), true);
}
```

But in [Laravel 5.7.29 PackageManifest.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.7.29/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php) , the same file is fixed:

```
if ($this->files->exists($path = $this->vendorPath.'/composer/installed.json')) {
    $installed = json_decode($this->files->get($path), true);

    $packages = $installed['packages'] ?? $installed;
}
```

Same goes for Laravel `5.6.0` that had the bug, and is fixed in `5.6.40` [Laravel 5.6.40 PackageManifest.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.6.40/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php). I don't know from which minor version it has been fixed at each level, but I suggest to go for the last, like `5.7.29`, `5.6.40` etc. Or you can go look the versions to see if it has been fixed.

NOW COMPOSER 2.0 IS VERY VERY FAST.

Answer (score 1):

here's a solution that worked for me. https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9340#issuecomment-716210369
change your laravel framework to 6.18.7 so that its compatible with composer 2

Answer (score 1):

If you have composer version 2 upgrade your laravel to 6.2.

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9340#issuecomment-716210369

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after i clone an laravel project and start composer install. Then I read through some solutions here. In my opinion, it is not a good idea to edit the laravel core. But if it's just for testing, why not.

My solution in my case was composer update instead composer install. In the case of composer update, it does not use the composer.lock file and updates the packages from composer.json. For me and in my special case works.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer composer version 2.0.9 was installed, I had the same problem when upgrade laravel project.

**the solution is :**

1. Delete **Vendor** folder inside your project if exist.
2. inside **composer.json** for laravel version write this `"laravel/framework": "^6.0"` don't forget ^ in front of 6.0 it needs to install latest version of laravel 6
3. then `composer update`

finally, it works perfectly.

Comment: Please don't forget to visit the Laravel docs upgrade guide, if you are increasing the framework version. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade

Answer (score 0):

**I got this issue because of a Laravel and composer version are not compatible.**

Following are the steps I follow to solve this issue:

1. I update Laravel version from 6.1 to 6.20 in composer.json file Eg: `"laravel/framework": "6.20.*"`
2. then delete composer.lock file.
3. And run `composer install` command

Now Problem is fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I've identified the root cause of this issue. The problem is that you've updated your machine's PHP version to a higher version, while your Laravel version is still below 6.20.

To fix this, please update your Laravel version by following these steps:

Update the 'laravel/framework' package to the latest version in the 6.x series.
Run 'composer update' to update your project's dependencies.
Finally, run 'composer install' to ensure all dependencies are properly installed.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your answer.

Answer (score -1):

run a composer upgrade.
This work for me on laravel 7

Answer (score -1):

If the error is after self updating the composer, just replace **composer** with **composer1**.
Just change:

```
composer install ...
```

into:

```
composer1 install ...
```

Just this!