# In session.php line 127: Class 'Str' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm trying to upgrade a Laravel project. I downloaded online to version 8 but on getting to version 6 I keep getting:

> In session.php line 127: Class 'Str' not found

in my command line. What am I doing wrong please.

This is line 127

```
Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
```

Comment: Did you `use Illuminate\Support\Str;`?

Comment: Please share more details, and your debugging attempts

Comment: Yes I used 'use Illuminate\Support\Str;'

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add

`use Illuminate\Support\Str;`

to the top of your `session.php` configuration file.

In version 5.0 this was never a thing and was introduced in Laravel 6.

References:

Laravel 5: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.0/config/session.php

Laravel 6: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/6.x/config/session.php

Comment: I already did that, got another error - In PackageManifest.php line 122:

  Undefined index: name

Comment: I tried this and it worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/64663892/14261398

Answer (score 0):

This error appears because laravel not able to find the namespace of `Str` try this.

on top of your file write this line `use Illuminate\Support\Str`  or simply `\Str`

Comment: I already did this. Another error popped up from PackageManefest. I have also added the str alias