# How to solve Laravel's Route 404 error on Login page?

Tags: php, laravel

A project, which is prepared with Laravel Framework, has handed over to me. Previous developer has not used git, some composer commands and Laravel's .gitignore file(also removed it). On the other hand he has prepared the project on the production server.

Anyway. Firstly I've found a gitignore for laravel and pushed the project to my repository. Then I wanted to pull it to my local. All folders and files pulled except of vendor folder.

Then I executed:

```
composer install
```

Gave me this error:

```
Class 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel' not found
```

Then I fixed it by the method [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/class-maatwebsiteexcelfacadesexcel-not-found-problem).

Then retried `composer install`, gave me this error:

```
Undefined index: name
```

Then fixed it by the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64663892/284199).

Then retried `composer install`, and succeeded. Then I cleared cache with `php artisan cache:clear`

I've configured `.env` file and tried to enter to homepage. It redirected me to login page and gave 404. I've checked the .htaccess, there was redirection like that:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/app/$1 [R=301,L]
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Changed the example.com to my localhost. But still gives me 404.

Is there anything that I'm missing?

**Note:** Called the previous developer, and he said me "directly copy and paste the all folders". Hi from 90s :(

Comment: Silly question but did you copy over the routes?

Comment: @AMR what do you mean by "copy over the routes". I haven't copied anything. Just git push and pull

Comment: okay let's go over what *should* be there for the pages to return correctly:
First you need a routes folder with with all the routes in files inside of it.
Second you need the Controller folder (found in /app/Http).
Third you need the resources folder with the actual views.
Fourth you need the public folder with the CSS/JS, etc.

If the routes are missing or the controller is missing you'll get an error page. Could you confirm that all of these exist?

Comment: I think you have a good point. My other views works well, but not login page

Comment: The previous dev, has changed the login router as loginhtdedwqa, so it can not find it

Comment: @AMR please write your suggestion with mine as answer

Comment: find out what the login view page is called, then go to your routes and make sure there's a line such as "Route::get('/login', 'SomeController@somefunction')->name('login.path');"
Then go to the controller that is referenced in that route, and make sure that the function returns the view of the login page

Comment: ok, worked. Please write it as answer, so I can assign this question as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP Said this worked for him so I'm moving it from comments to an answer:

Let's go over what should be there for the pages to return correctly: First you need a routes folder with with all the routes in files inside of it. Second you need the Controller folder (found in /app/Http). Third you need the resources folder with the actual views. Fourth you need the public folder with the CSS/JS, etc.

---

Since OP stated that all the views work except for the login view:

First find out what the login view page is called, then go to your routes and make sure there's a line such as

```
Route::get('/login', 'SomeController@somefunction')->name('login.path');
```

Then go to the controller that is referenced in that route, and make sure that the function returns the view of the login page

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to generate you laravel application key using `php artisan key:generate`.

If that also doesn't work then try to remove `.htaccess` temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel:^3.0
```

Comment: run composer update and composer dump-autoload  in server terminal.

Comment: config/app.php 'providers' => [
    Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
],
'aliases' => [
    'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
]  Add the ServiceProvider and Facade